# Why is a Silverlight button hard to click by touch on an HP Touchsmart?

Tags: silverlight, touch

I am using Silverlight to develop an application that we anticipate will be used heavily on touch screen monitors in the healthcare setting.  I am finding that simple controls like Button, or even simpler primitive controls that I've written myself to capture mouse events, are very flaky and unresponsive on an HP Touchsmart.  Many times clicks do not even register, but the behavior is entirely unpredictable.

Any idea why a plain old Silverlight button is hard to click by touch on an HP Touchsmart?

Comment: I think you'd be better off using WPF, honestly - maybe go the XBAP route instead of Silverlight? Which version of Silverlight, by the way? It may be better in 3.0.

Comment: You could try comparing the responsiveness to a WPF app to see how much of the problem is Silverlight.  What OS are you running?

Comment: This is Vista 64.  We have a bunch of reasons for wanting to be web-based right now, so Silverlight it is.  It seems to be the hardware itself is just somewhat unresponsive.  It registers touches slower than clicks register on a regular PC.  Sometimes it seems to just miss a touch altogether.

Comment: After looking into this some more, it appears that with a primitive control, MouseDown doesn't always fire, but MouseUp always does.  This causes Button elements not to raise Click (MouseDown and MouseUp both need to happen in the same element).  This is problematic for situations like drag and drop, where you really want to know where mousedown vs. mouseup occurred.  I wonder why mousedown is iffy with silverlight controls on the touchsmart?

Comment: Yes, actually, this was a while back, but I believe the problem was that MouseUp or Click didn't always register, so we had to use a solution that triggered click events on MouseDown.  If you create a simple SilverLight project that can log MouseDown, MouseUp, and Click, you will quickly see which ones are (for whatever reason) not registered on the HP TouchSmart computers.